# ftp via powershell - how to indicate success

Tags: powershell, ftp

I'm using a Powershell script to automate sending a .txt to an FTP site. When I execute it in powershell, nothing happens. The root\prompt just appears...no messages that it was successful. How do I tell if it worked? Here is my script in case it helps.

---

```
$localfile = "D:\Export\TESTING.txt"
$remotefile = "/TESTING.txt"
$ftphost = "ftp://ftp.site.com"
$URI = $ftphost + $remotefile
$username="USERNAME"
$password="1234"
function Get-FTPFile 
($URI,$localfile,$username,$password){
$credentials=New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential
($username,$password)
$ftp=[System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($URI)
$ftp.Credentials=$credentials
$ftp.UseBinary=1
$ftp.KeepAlive=0
$response=$ftp.GetResponse()
$responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
$file = New-Object 
IO.FileStream ($localfile,[IO.FileMode]::Create)
[byte[]]$buffer = New-Object byte[] 1024
$read = 0
do{
$read=$responseStream.Read($buffer,0,1024)
$file.Write($buffer,0,$read)
}
while ($read -ne 0)$file.close()
}
```

Comment: Was my answer sufficient, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize` following completion of the upload to confirm that the uploaded file size matches the local file size.

You could also use a try/catch block to check for exceptions during your read/write operations.  A lack of exceptions would give you some confidence that the upload was successful (i.e. no news is good news).